# ThreeJS Error (Three.WebGLRenderer: x.getContext is not a function. Uncaught TypeError: x.getContent is not a function)

Tags: three.js

When I run the following in my localhost, it runs as expected, but when I attempt to run it in my server - I get the error noted above. I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I'm very new to ThreeJS. Any help is appreciated. The error stems from renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer().This is what I have in my index.html:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>opuni</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }

        canvas {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <script src="js/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/postprocessing.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        let scene, camera, cloudParticles = [], composer;
        function init() {
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
            camera.position.z = 1;
            camera.rotation.x = 1.16;
            camera.rotation.y = -0.12;
            camera.rotation.z = 0.27;

            let ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x555555);
            scene.add(ambient);

            let directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xff8c19);
            directionalLight.position.set(0,0,1);
            scene.add(directionalLight);

            let orangeLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xe7552c, 50, 450, 1.7);
            orangeLight.position.set(200, 300, 100);
            scene.add(orangeLight);
            let redLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffb745, 50, 450, 1.7);
            redLight.position.set(100, 300, 100);
            scene.add(redLight);
            let blueLight = new THREE.PointLight(0x5cc5ef, 50, 450, 1.7);
            blueLight.position.set(300, 300, 200);
            scene.add(blueLight);

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x344d90, 0.001);
            renderer.setClearColor(scene.fog.color);
            document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
            loader.load("img/home/smoke.png", function(texture){
                cloudGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(500,500);
                cloudMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                    map:texture,
                    transparent: true
                });

                for(let p=0; p<75; p++) {
                    let cloud = new THREE.Mesh(cloudGeo, cloudMaterial);
                    cloud.position.set(
                        Math.random()*800 -400,
                        500,
                        Math.random()*500-500
                    );
                    cloud.rotation.x = 1.16;
                    cloud.rotation.y = -0.12;
                    cloud.rotation.z = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
                    cloud.material.opacity = 0.55;
                    cloudParticles.push(cloud)
                    scene.add(cloud);
                }
            });

            loader.load("img/home/milkyway.jpg", function(texture){

                const textureEffect = new POSTPROCESSING.TextureEffect({
                    blendFunction: POSTPROCESSING.BlendFunction.COLOR_DODGE,
                    texture: texture
                });
                textureEffect.blendMode.opacity.value = 0.2;
                const bloomEffect = new POSTPROCESSING.BloomEffect({
                    blendFunction: POSTPROCESSING.BlendFunction.COLOR_DODGE,
                    kernelSize: POSTPROCESSING.KernelSize.SMALL,
                    useLuminanceFilter: true,
                    luminanceThreshold: 0.5,
                    luminanceSmoothing: 0.75
                });

                bloomEffect.blendMode.opacity.value = 1.5;

                let effectPass = new POSTPROCESSING.EffectPass(
                    camera,
                    bloomEffect,
                    textureEffect
                );
                effectPass.renderToScreen = true;

                composer = new POSTPROCESSING.EffectComposer(renderer);
                composer.addPass(new POSTPROCESSING.RenderPass(scene, camera));
                composer.addPass(effectPass);

                render();
            });
        }
        function render() {
            cloudParticles.forEach(p => {
                p.rotation.z -=0.001;
            });
            composer.render(0.1);
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
        }
        init();
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is `js/postprocessing.min.js`? It does not seem this code belongs to the official `three.js` repository. Besides, can you please note where the runtime error occurs(file, line)? What version of `three.js` are you using? Demonstrating the issue with a live example will make it easier to investigate it.

Comment: @Mugen87 Hi! I'm using r109 of ThreeJs.  postprocessing.min.js was used to provide a post processing effect. it was taken from here: [link](https://github.com/vanruesc/postprocessing) . You can find a live example of my page not working at [link](https://www.opuni.co) I was working off of the following tutorial from youtube [link] ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5f5wwQb22tE&feature=youtu.be). The error stems from line 43 (renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer) and line 111 ( init() ).

Comment: Can you please use an unminified version of `three.js` in your app for debugging purposes?

Comment: @Mugen87 I switched to the unminified version of three.js, and pushed it to the live example.  I now see the error originating at line 23535 of three.js ( _gl = _context || _canvas.getContext( 'webgl', contextAttributes ) || _canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl', contextAttributes ); ).

Comment: I'm not sure why this happens but the renderer's internal canvas created via `document.createElementNS( 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', 'canvas' )` is not of type `HTMLCanvasElement` but just `Element`. Thus, `getContext()` is not available. Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce this on my system...

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks for all of your time and help. I really appreciate it.